# Recursion implementation of LeetCode Problem

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

**Problem Name** : 413. Arithmetic Slices 
**Problem Statement** : 
A sequence of number is called arithmetic if it consists of at least three elements and if the difference between any two consecutive elements is the same.

For example, these are arithmetic sequence:

1, 3, 5, 7, 9
7, 7, 7, 7
3, -1, -5, -9

The following sequence is not arithmetic.

1, 1, 2, 5, 7

A zero-indexed array A consisting of N numbers is given. A slice of that array is any pair of integers (P, Q) such that 0 <= P < Q < N.

A slice (P, Q) of array A is called arithmetic if the sequence:
A[P], A[p + 1], ..., A[Q - 1], A[Q] is arithmetic. In particular, this means that P + 1 < Q.

The function should return the number of arithmetic slices in the array A.

**LINK** : https://leetcode.com/problems/arithmetic-slices/

---

I was trying to find out a recursive algorithm for the above problem. I was trying to implement the algorithm which basically take portions of the array and recursively solves the issue until the array size reaches the length == 3. At length == 3 we check whether the array is arithmatic and return 1 or 0 based on that.

**My Solution**:

```
def isArithmatic(array):
    if (array[1] - array[0]) == (array[2] - array[1]):
        return True
    return False
def arithmaticSlices(array):
    if len(array) == 3:
        if isArithmatic(array):
            return 1
        return 0
    else:    
        return arithmaticSlices(array[1:]) + arithmaticSlices(array[:len(array)-1])
```

**MY QUESTION**: The answer that the code is returning is lesser than the original answer. Please help.

Comment: The solution is wrong because it does not count for any arithmetic slices that have a length over 3.

Comment: Thanks GZ0 for response. How can we deal with that case?

Comment: You can find various solutions on the website if you cannot figure it out yourself.

Comment: Yes I can, But as I have implemented this solution I wanted to get help in this specific algorithm so that I can be sure that certain things can be improved when we work on future solutions.

Comment: Actually, your solution not only overlooks some arithmetic slices, it also counts some slices twice because `array[1:]` and `array[:-1]` have a large overlap. I don't see a quick fix without some radical changes.

Comment: Why do you want to implement a recursive version? An iterative one [like this](https://tio.run/##fVLZasMwEHz3VwzkxaIpJDGlEOovMSYIW46XypKroyVf70qW07jpoSdpj5nZWY0X12tVTFMrOpA9cUOuH4SjJrfizQvVCHbMEI5CCSnULTxHN6AOrhcxdXZ9gAg3a0OIKxRbGOG8Uei4tGJuCOUKLygSaDw/SjbQAdF8kBVo9DB6J8ClnGla6jphIr8FVy2aXjSvi4bLXMWNmCstHxJcbAnaq6vwimo84vYKj32NThsQSMFwdRb5fgvF6mylL2DnLcpyxqt2qaONHTHAsiw6aCUFZadGe@XuDdwsYqPI6xgudSzuWeSd0QMKOP0lcMld7Y5D3yE4bhypM0ZtyZFWdpFtvXRh8N0/64szWHkKidvoYWsKD9izY@TzYxQT0430lt7Fam8zwUMJ64f8979T0ZECVqKo2b3LKi4i0UdCtvY7wWfZaCh6uTa2CtsJKp@2eK4ZQzKm@Kvy8L14g0M2TZ8) does the job very well.

Comment: yes I understand. Actually I am still in a learning stage. So trying to implement it in actual problems. Anyway Thanks for your help @GZ0.

Comment: Thanks for response @trolley813. Actually I am learning recursion thatswhy wanted to implement it with that.  Thanks for the link

Comment: For a recursive solution to work you need to be able to find the correct connection between the original problem's solution and a smaller problem's solution. The website offers one recursive solution. You can try to read the algorithm description and then implement it yourself before looking at the provided code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one answer accepted by LeetCode. I hope the simple logic makes sense:

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(A, i=2, total=0, prevSeqTotal=0){
  if (i >= A.length)
    return total

  // The number of sequences ending here is 1 (length 3)
  // plus the number ending at the previous
  // element since those all just got extended.
  if (A[i] - A[i-1] == A[i-1] - A[i-2])
    return f(A, i + 1, total + 1 + prevSeqTotal, 1 + prevSeqTotal)

  return f(A, i + 1, total, 0)
}

console.log(f([3, 1, -1, -3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following array:

```
1, 3, 5, 7
```

You code counts `1, 3, 5` and `3, 5, 7`. However, it fails to count `1, 3, 5, 7` (which is an arithmetic slice of length 4).

Comment: Thanks @NPE for response. What changes can we do to deal those cases? Any suggestions.